# Load attributes form json to javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a data in json file those look like this:

```
{"NAME": "name1", "value1":5, "value2":4, "value3":9}
{"NAME": "name2", "value1":3, "value2":8, "value3":2}
{"NAME": "name3", "value1":5, "value2":8, "value3":2}
```

I like to load this data into 3 javascript arrays and show it on webiste in this way:

table1:

```
NAME   value1
name1  5
name2  3
name3  5
```

table2:

```
NAME   value2
name1  4
name2  8
name3  8
```

How is the best way to do it in using js/jquery?
I suppose is a easy thing but I'm beginner in js/jquery and I still have a problems with basic things.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have the option to edit the file? The file is not valid json since it contains 3 separate json fragments. If you do have the option to edit the file put the 3 objects in a single json array like this:
[
{"NAME": "name1", "value1":5, "value2":4, "value3":9},
{"NAME": "name2", "value1":3, "value2":8, "value3":2},
{"NAME": "name3", "value1":5, "value2":8, "value3":2}
]

Comment: Hi, yes I can edit the json file, I've just improved file as you told

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fiddle here for you](http://jsfiddle.net/ynnjjayg/)

Create List.
Iterate through the list and create new objects.
Iterate through new list and create HTML.
Put in div container.

```
var list = [
    {"NAME": "name1", "value1":5, "value2":4, "value3":9}
    {"NAME": "name2", "value1":3, "value2":8, "value3":2}
    {"NAME": "name3", "value1":5, "value2":8, "value3":2}
];

var table1, table2, table3;
var newList = [];

$.each(list, function(index, val) {
    table1 = {
       name: val.NAME,
       value: val.value1
    }

    table2 = {
      name: val.NAME,
      value: val.value2
    };

    table3 = {
      name: val.NAME,
      value: val.value3
    }

    createdList.push(table1);
    createdList.push(table2);
    createdList.push(table3);
});

var createdTable;
$.each(table1, function(index, val) {
    createdTable += '<tr><td>' + val.name + '</td>';
    createdTable += '<td>' + val.value + '</td></tr>';
});

// do the same for the others
$('#someID').html('<table>' + createdTable + '</table>');
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to make sure that the JSON code is valid.

```
var data = '{"NAME": "name1", "value1":5, "value2":4, "value3":9}';
data = JSON.parse(data); //Parse JSON to access data values
document.write(data.Name);// prints -> name1
document.write(data.value); // prints -> 5
document.write(data.value2); // prints -> 4
```

since you have 3 separate json arrays, you need to make sure they're in a single array which will look something like this

```
data = ['{"NAME": "name1", "value1":5, "value2":4, "value3":9}','{"NAME": "name1", "value1":5, "value2":4, "value3":9}','{"NAME": "name1", "value1":5, "value2":4, "value3":9}']
```

Now parse the array.

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
document.write(data[0].NAME)// Prints first json array NAME value
document.write(data[1].NAME)// Print second json array NAME value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr1='[{"NAME": "name1", "value1":5, "value2":4, "value3":9}]';
var arr2='[{"NAME": "name2", "value1":3, "value2":8, "value3":2}]';
var arr3='[{"NAME": "name3", "value1":5, "value2":8, "value3":2}]';
    var html='<table><tr><th width="100">NAME</th><th width="100">Value1</th><th width="100">Value2</th><th width="100">Value3</th></tr>'; 
    $.each(JSON.parse(arr1), function(idx, obj) {
        html += '<tr><td width="100">' + obj.NAME + '</td>';
        html += '<td width="100">' + obj.value1 + '</td>';  
        html += '<td width="100">' + obj.value2 + '</td>';  
        html += '<td width="100">' + obj.value3 + '</td></tr>'; 
    });
    $.each(JSON.parse(arr2), function(idx, obj) {
        html += '<tr><td width="100">' + obj.NAME + '</td>';
        html += '<td width="100">' + obj.value1 + '</td>';  
        html += '<td width="100">' + obj.value2 + '</td>';  
        html += '<td width="100">' + obj.value3 + '</td></tr>'; 
    });
    $.each(JSON.parse(arr3), function(idx, obj) {
        html += '<tr><td width="100">' + obj.NAME + '</td>';
        html += '<td width="100">' + obj.value1 + '</td>';  
        html += '<td width="100">' + obj.value2 + '</td>';  
        html += '<td width="100">' + obj.value3 + '</td></tr>'; 
    });
    html+='</table>'
    $('body').append(html);
```

Can find it in **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hdjvs2h3/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object.keys(obj) on an object and then map through it and assign the element on that key to the array at the k index.

```
var o = {"NAME": "name1", "value1":5, "value2":4, "value3":9};

var arr = [];
Object.keys(o).map(function(k) { arr[k] = o[k]; });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1678es42/